# How do I check out only top level of externals?

Tags: svn

When i check out a source tree for development when not using externals, i do the following: -

```
svn co --depth immediates <repo>/trunk <location>
```

and then svn update --set-depth infinity on the subdirectories i want to work on.

However, the trunk i am working on now is made up of externals from other areas in the repo.

If i do the checkout --depth immediates, i do not get the top level of the externals (i just get an empty directory).

Is this a fault or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a design issue or, as they say, a defined feature:

[How to fetch a Subversion external without fetching all other directories and subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019246/how-to-fetch-a-subversion-external-without-fetching-all-other-directories-and-su)

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3311

Comment: Thanks ... I'll keep and eye on that issue report and hold my breath for it being fixed :)